# JavaScript for loop value not updating inside of loop

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop

I am working on project dealing with the Google Maps API and I am trying to get the duration between multiple trips and tell what trips are shorter based on time. I was getting weird values in my object so I put some print statements outside of the directionsService and inside of it to. Code:

```
  //loop through all the trips being made
  for (i = 0; i < destinationsArray.length; i++) {
    //request holds the information for the directions request
    var request = {
      origin: destinationsArray[i].from, 
      destination: destinationsArray[i].to, 
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
      transitOptions: {
        modes: ['BUS'],
        routingPreference: 'LESS_WALKING',
        arrivalTime: today.now, 
      } 
     }
     let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     let companyID = destinationsArray[i].id;
     console.log(i + " outside")
     directionsService.route(request, function(reponse, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log(i + " inside")
        //create a new direction render for clickable options
        let dirRender = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
        //push this new direction render onto the array 
        directionsRenderers.push(dirRender)
        //create object to hold data about this current trip: trip length and company name
        let tripInformation = {duration: reponse.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value, id: companyID}
        //put this var into array
        //console.log(tripInformation)
        durationArray.push(tripInformation)
        //this line puts the trip onto the map to see
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(reponse);
      } else {
        alert("Could not display directions due to: " + status);
      }
    }
  );
  }
```

the print statements are coming out like so:
0 outside
1 outside
0 inside
0 inside

the destinationsArray is here if needed:

```
var destinationsArray = [
  {id: "Trip 1", to: "John Ball Park Zoo", from: "Rosa Parks Circle"},
  {id: "Trip 2", to: "10897 48th Ave NW", from: "1 Campus Drive Allendale"}
];
```

Comment: this is normal behavior. with `directionsService.route` you are sending an async request. The request's can take different amount of time to finished.

Comment: @Sysix I suspected that could be the possibility. How might I attach the companyID if the two are out of sync?

Comment: maybe splitting it into function would help, looks like a scope problem for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```js
for(x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(x))   // Outputs 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
}
```

Versus this:

```js
    for(let x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(x))   // Outputs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    }
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript/500459#500459) for detailed explanation

Comment: another reason why I live modern IDE's :) They give automatic warning's when you didn't define a variable